# Issue Inserting data from php to database

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm having issues inserting data into a database from php (API URL). Below I have a php I believe all the details are correct.

First time doing this, so i'm not 100% sure how to debug, the data is not appearing in the table.

Some help our tips would be great.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "player";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


$f_pointer=fopen("https://www.url.com/api/csv/xxx?    apikey=xxxxxxxxx=2","r"); 

while(! feof($f_pointer)){
    $ar=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
$sql="INSERT INTO     scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('$ar[0]','$ar[1]','$ar[2]','$ar[3]')";
echo $sql;
echo "<br>";
    }
?>


mysql> DESCRIBE scores;
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pos        | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| errorthing | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| name       | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| total      | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

Example output

```
INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('--','javascript:void(0);','Scott Verplank','--')<br>INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('--','javascript:void(0);','Bill','--')<br>INSERT INTO scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('--','javascript:void(0);','John','--')
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot to execute the insert sql statement in code. mysqli_query is missing in your while loop code.

Comment: $conn->query($sql); //before your echo...

Comment: also... you need a field with auto-increment.. into your db... ex.: "id"...

Comment: And you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 0):

> Use [mysqli->query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

after your query

```
 $sql="INSERT INTO     scores(pos,errorthing,name,total)values('$ar[0]','$ar[1]','$ar[2]','$ar[3]')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

this will do the trick